# Problema con el conector MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans

Tengo un problema:

He realizado una aplicación de Escritorio en NetBeans con Maven que conecta con una base de datos MySQL.

Si ejecuto el programa desde NetBeans, me conecta correctamente con la BBDD. Pero si ejecuto el jar desde el ordenador, éste me da error de conexión en la BBDD (la BBDD y el servidor se están ejecutando correctamente).

He probado a cambiar la dependencia que obtuve en el repositorio de maven, ya que el conector de MySQL de mi equipo es el 8.0.28 y el que uso en NetBeans es el 8.0.18.

Cuando ejecuto la aplicación con el 8.0.28 se conecta correctamente, pero muestra el siguiente error:

```
Conectado Correctamente a la Base de Datos Local pelisseries
java.sql.SQLException: Operation not allowed for a result set of type ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY.
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:129)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.result.ResultSetImpl.last(ResultSetImpl.java:1787)
    at ddr.pelisseries.modelo.peliculasBD.getDatosPelisVistas(peliculasBD.java:66)
    at ddr.pelisseries.controlador.Controlador.getDatosPelisVistas(Controlador.java:12)
    at ddr.pelisseries.vista.GUIPelisVistas.<init>(GUIPelisVistas.java:28)
    at ddr.pelisseries.vista.GUIPrincipal.PelisVistasActionPerformed(GUIPrincipal.java:186)
    at ddr.pelisseries.vista.GUIPrincipal$1.actionPerformed(GUIPrincipal.java:64)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1972)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2313)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:405)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:262)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:279)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6626)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3389)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6391)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2266)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:5001)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2324)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4833)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4948)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4575)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4516)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2310)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2780)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4833)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:773)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:722)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:716)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:97)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:746)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:744)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:743)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
```

Y en mi programa me dirije a este módulo: a la línea de   rs.last();

```
public static Object[][] getDatosPelisVistas() {

    Object[][] obj = null;
    
    try (Connection con = new ConexionBD().conectarBD();) {
        if (con == null) {
            System.out.println("Error conexión");
        } else {
            String sql = "SELECT * FROM peliculas ORDER BY titulo";
            try (Statement st = con.createStatement();) {
                ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sql);
                ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
                rs.last();
                int numCols = rsmd.getColumnCount();
                int numFils = rs.getRow();
                obj = new Object[numFils][numCols];
                int j = 0;
                rs.beforeFirst();
                while (rs.next()) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < numCols; i++) {
                        obj[j][i] = rs.getObject(i + 1);
                    }
                    j++;
                }
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(GUIPrincipal.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    return obj;
}
```

¿Sabéis por qué?  ¿Es problema de código?
Porque con el conector 8.018 me funciona correctamente y con el 8.0.28 no funciona :(

Comment: El error (la excepción) se produce a partir de la versión 8.0.20 del conector (Connector/J).

Comment: Ok, gracias @wchiquito. Veré cómo depurar entonces el código para usar el conector más actual.

Comment: Verifique la Release Notes (Connector/J) de la versión 8.0.20 para detalles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De acuerdo al error:

> SQLException: Operation not allowed for a result set of type
> ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY.

Esto quiere decir que tratas de obtener un valor del `ResultSet` hacia atrás y la configuración de tipo `TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY` indica que solo puede avanzar de registro en registro hacia adelante.

Por lo tanto, **únicamente deberías usar `.next()`**, ya que estás moviendo el cursor hacia el último elemento y posteriormente regresas a la posición predeterminada.

```
 ...
 rs.last();
 ...
 ...
 rs.beforeFirst();
 ...
```

**Si deseas que el `ResultSet` sea totalmente navegable, puedes configurar el `ResultSet` usando `TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE`** :

```
con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
```

---

[**Tipos de ResultSet**](https://www.ibm.com/docs/es/i/7.2?topic=resultsets-resultset-characteristics)

El tipo de un `ResultSet` especifica los siguiente acerca del `ResultSet`:

Si el `ResultSet` es desplazable.
Los tipos de los ResultSets de Java™ Database Connectivity (JDBC) definidos por constantes en la interfaz ResultSet.
Las definiciones de estos tipos de ResultSet son las siguientes:

**TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY**

Un cursor que solo puede utilizarse para procesar desde el principio de un ResultSet hasta el final del mismo. Este es el tipo por omisión.

**TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE**

Un cursor que se puede emplear para desplazares a través de un ResultSet. Este tipo de cursor es insensible a los cambios efectuados en la base de datos mientras está abierto. Contiene filas que satisfacen la consulta cuando esta se procesa o cuando se extraen datos.

**TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE**

Un cursor que puede utilizarse para el desplazamiento en diversas formas a través de un ResultSet. Este tipo de cursor es sensible a los cambios efectuados en la base de datos mientras está abierto. Los cambios en la base de datos tienen un impacto directo sobre los datos del ResultSet.

Comment: gracias por el doc. Lo acabo de aplicar y funciona perfectamente.

Comment: Excelente @ErDany !, saludos.